# System.CalloutException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable" ERROR

Tags: apex, api, webservices, httprequest, post

I'm trying to make an HTTP Request to other System.

They provided the endpoint URL which contains a Port number.

https://Test.com:50001/RESTAP/BGN/PRDV/CREATE

When I'm trying to make the request I'm facing this ERROR:

> System.CalloutException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns
>   "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable"

although I have added the URL in remote sites.

When I make the request from Postman - I get the response as expected.
So I don't think it about the Ip address, because when I used postman - I tried to use my internal network\ wifi public network and my mobile phone network.. all of them have different IP Address and all of them succeeded and I got the response...

My code is :

```
Http httpProtocol = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        String url = 'https://Test.com:50001/RESTAP/BGN/PRDV/CREATE';
        String username2 = 'Name';
        String password2 = 'Passowrd';
        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username2 + ':' + password2);
        String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
        request.setEndpoint(url);
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
        request.setTimeout(60000);


        request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        request.setHeader('proxyPort','50001');
        request.setHeader('proxyHost','PROXYHOST URL');
        request.setHeader('proxySet','true');

        HttpResponse response = httpProtocol.send(request);
```

Note: The userName and Password will be filled from Custom setting.

I tried with and without the proxy header, I tried to turn the BASIC auth to Basic (lower-case letter) and many other little changes that didn't work.

I also tried to use Named Credentials to handle the auth.

But i'm still getting this Error.

How can I know if it not blocked by Firewall? and if it does, what should I do?

Because I'm getting this error - I'm assuming that the client does not get the request at all.

Any help or Idea to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: would be a good idea if you can use postman from outside of your company's network? that would tell you, if the url is good for calls originating from external applications like Salesforce.

Comment: Hi @SFNinja, Thanks for your time!  I tried to connect to three different networks: internal network - (which won't be really objective) wifi public network - which serve guests - So internal services won't work with this IP -  and my mobile phone network - Other Ip Address...